# Is there a trope for a pile-on fight?

Tags: trope

Is there a trope about one person being tackled and piled on and the hero uses tremendous strength to get up and the multiple opponents go flying? Here is what I am talking about from *The Matrix Reloaded*:

[image]

I want to see if rare human beings actually fought people all at once and not one at a time.

Comment: Well, if you consider TVTropes a reliable source, they call it [Dog Pile of Doom](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DogPileOfDoom).

Comment: Thank you, this is a what if question, what in your opinion would be reliable sources of what you are talking about

Comment: @Walt Well, you probably won't get more reliable than that when it's about "tropes" (not implying that it's reliable enough at all, though).

Comment: Fair enough. I'll put it up, then.

Comment: One more question, is it reliable for writers?

Comment: Doubt it. Better call it 'dogpile on the hero' or 'action movie dogpile' or something like that. What you called it in the title also seems clear enough.

Comment: In your opinion, what is reliable for writers?

Answer (score 8):

Online trope compiler TvTropes has decided to call this one [Dog Pile of Doom](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DogPileOfDoom):

> A large number of mooks jump on the hero, pinning him down.
>
> Usually it's a climactic battle scene. The hero is facing down dozens, no, hundreds, no, THOUSANDS of Mooks. At first, the hero's doing well. He's smiting them one after another. But then he begins to get tired, and first one, then another, then another and another and another leap onto him, dragging the poor guy to the ground.

It seems you're after the first scenario mentioned there:

> There are several ways that this scene can turn out:
>
> Type A: The hero activates a super mode, has an epiphany, or otherwise becomes more Bad Ass. He explodes out of the pile, minions scattering to the four winds, and rises as an epic figure.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't want to do anything this afternoon anyway.

Comment: One law that often governs this type of situation is the [Conservation of Ninjutsu](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu).